# sql query to filter the results based on substring

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

SQL table has the following data, with 3 columns

Id,
Name and
Full Name.

```
| ID | Name | FullName |
| 1  |  a   | a        |
| 2  |  b   | ab       |
| 3  |  c   | abc      |
| 4  |  d   | ad       |
| 5  |  e   | ade      |
| 6  |  i   | i        |
| 7  |  g   | ig       |
```

For example, in the rows where ID =1 and , Full Name column value(s) are  'a' and 'ab'. This data is a substring in the row 3 (id =3) Full Name column data 'abc'.

How to exclude the rows Id =1 and Id =2 because the 'full  name' column data is a substring to the FullName column value 'abc' in row Id =3.

**Desired output**

```
| ID | Name | FullName |
| 3  |  c   | abc      |
| 5  |  e   | ade      |
| 7  |  g   | ig       |
```

Comment: You should accept one of the answers given below.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    ID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(45),
    FullName VARCHAR(90)
    );
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES
(1, 'a', 'a'),
(2, 'b', 'ab'),
(3, 'c', 'abc'),
(4, 'd', 'ad'),
(5, 'e', 'ade'),
(6, 'i', 'i'),
(7, 'g', 'ig');

SELECT *
FROM MyTable 
WHERE ID NOT IN (
                        SELECT DISTINCT T1.ID
                        FROM MyTable T1 INNER JOIN MyTable T2
                        ON T1.ID <> T2.ID
                        AND T2.FullName LIKE '%' + T1.FullName + '%'
                );
```

Results:

```
+----+----+------+----------+
|    | ID | Name | FullName |
+----+----+------+----------+
|  1 |  3 | c    | abc      |
|  2 |  5 | e    | ade      |
|  3 |  7 | g    | ig       |
+----+----+------+----------+
```

Comment: Smart solution indeed. It is possible to use it to solve "the complementary" problem (i.e. extract rows with values contained in other rows), we just need to change the last line as   AND T1.FullName LIKE T2.FullName + '%'  
This way you get  rows with ID=1 and ID=6

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query which seems to be working.  We can phrase a matching full name as one for which there are no parents of that full name.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                WHERE t2.FullName LIKE '%' + t1.FullName + '%' AND
                      LEN(t2.FullName) > LEN(t1.FullName));
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: I cannot cast vote, solution is really helpful.

Comment: @sss you can set it as accepted answer